# Why is my animation glitching?

Tags: unity, animation, 3dsmax

The Animations done is 3ds max works great and smooth as they should be, problem happens when i import them to unity, they seems to be glitching and noncontinuous at some parts, all i did was splitting the animations based on the frame sheet given by the animator.
Maybe I'm missing somethings ?

Comment: This will be very difficult for us to diagnose unless you can show us the symptoms you're experiencing and exactly what operations you performed on the animations. Remember, we can't see anything about your project except what you provide to us.